# What is in trend in Mac OSX world Pkg or Dmg?

Tags: macos, package, installation, dmg

As DMG and PKG both are widely used for installation in Mac OSX. I have seen many DMG in the last decade, now I see more PKGs.

I need to ship an app that is around 100 MB, I am not sure what installation style should I choose.

So why people moved to PKGs from DMGs?
Is there any Apple documentation that says what and when to use?

Comment: +1 for a detailed answer to this question. I'm the only one that feels that there's a lack of information around how to properly create an installer for macOS?

Answer (score 7):

If you need to run some scripts pre or post installation of your app, then pkgs need to be used. If you just need the app to be copied to Dmg